# Does P(Y|X)=const. in the whole P(Y,X) imply that P(X|Y) also remains constant? Or is covariate shift the same as label shift?

Tags: machine-learning, conditional-probability, covariate-shift, data-drift

I research covariate shift solutions for ML models. Some papers/books (e.g. "Probabilistic Machine Learning" by Kevin Murphy) claim that one needs different solutions for covariate and label shifts, I claim they are the same.

Definitions:

**Covariate shift** - P(Y|X) remains the same, P(X) changes between source and target domains.

**Label shift** - P(X|Y) remains the same, P(Y) changes between source and target domains.

Difference between these two: causality. We speak about covariate shift when X->Y and label shift otherwise.

I claim that if P(Y|X) changes in any point of the feature space X then P(X|Y) changes in the corresponding point of the label space. Therefore, assumption that P(Y|X)=const. implies that P(X|Y)=const. as well in the whole joint P(Y,X).

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

No, $P(Y\mid X)$ remaining unchanged over time does not imply that $P(X\mid Y)$ also remains unchanged.

For a small example, take the two discrete distributions:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
0.2 & 0.1 \\
0.3 & 0.4 
\end{pmatrix}
,\qquad
\begin{pmatrix}
0.3 & 0.05 \\
0.45 & 0.2
\end{pmatrix}
$$

with $X$ indexing the columns and $Y$ the rows.  Then (because the columns are constant multiples from one dist. to the other) $P(Y\mid X)$ is the same for the two, but $P(X\mid Y)$ is not.  So this is an instance of covariate shift, but not label shift.

Comment: Thank you for replying.

Let's assume X and Y can take values 1 and 2. The first joint distribution is:  


P(X=1, Y=1)=0.2
P(X=1, Y=2)=0.3
P(X=2, Y=1)=0.1
P(X=2, Y=2)=0.4

Conditionals of the 1st first distribution:  

P(Y|X=1) = 1 with P=0.2, 2 with P=0.3
P(Y|X=2) = 1 with P=0.1, 2 with P=0.4
P(X|Y=1) = 1 with P=0.2, 2 with P=0.1
P(X|Y=2) = 1 with P=0.3, 2 with P=0.4

2nd:

P(Y|X=1) = 1 with P=0.3, 2 with P=0.45
P(Y|X=2) = 1 with P=0.05, 2 with P=0.2
P(X|Y=1) = 1 with P=0.3, 2 with P=0.05
P(X|Y=2) = 1 with P=0.45, 2 with P=0.2

Aren't they all different?

Comment: Sorry for bad formatting of the comment. I couln't make line split (or I don't know how). I hope you will read it and share your thoughts.

Comment: It seems that I got confused on conditionals. The condition is *given* so all the events given the condition should sum up to 1.